# Classifier with multiple datatypes (Machine Learning / Datascience)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, multiclass-classification

I am a beginner to Machine Learning / Datascience. I have prepared a dataset and it includes partially categorical columns, datetime objects and numerical columns. The target is a multiclass item (~ 6 classes). I am working with Jupyter Notebook and Python.

So far I have tried a simple example like using a SVM Learner:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiclass-classification-using-scikit-learn/

How do I handle the different datatypes? Is there a classifier that can handle all types well?
For the datetime objects my idea is to change them to minutes since zero (~ year 1972?). Then I would have only categroical and numeric data.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Categorical columns - One hot encoding, or a response coding.
Datetime Objects - Yes you are right, Instead of minutes make it to year (depends how old data you have.) Anyway, you will be doing normalization it doesn't matter but for older data like you mentioned the year 1972, It can help you visualize better in years if feature importance is required. Also, you can go for the binning of years [1972 - 1982] and so on and see what works best for you. Most of the time it's problem-specific.
Numeric data - you don't have to do anything. Eventually, you have to change your features into numbers so that any machine learning algorithms can work.
 Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

For your categorical features your need to do label encoding on them so that your machine can understand it, and (year 1972) if you have something like this in your feature then first you need to remove year from all your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).